# How to remove the inline error view in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I find this inline error view in vs code pretty annoying when jumping to an error, is there any way to remove it?

[image: inline error message I want removed]

I have tried looking through the settings, but there doesn't seem to be any obvious way to remove this. Google didn't help very much either.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If you don't have that, then how do you know what the error is? Do you hover over the line? Or are the errors you're dealing with always obvious?

Comment: @wjandrea I prefer to read the error in the terminal or problems tab instead. 99% of my errors are obvious.

Comment: then fix the obvious error if you see the squiggles and you do not get the peek window

Comment: @rioV8 I don't have the automatic error detection with the error squiggles enabled since I have found it to be marking something that isn't actually an error which is annoying aswell. I can only notice my errors when I compile my program and that is how I want it to be. I program in C.

Comment: with the extension [When File](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.WhenFile) you can make the squiggles transparent when the file is dirty/not saved

Comment: @rioV8 Even when everything compiles fine and the file is saved, vscode can still mark part of my code as an error when there clearly isn't any.

Comment: do you have a linter running

Comment: @rioV8 If I enable a linter, the same problem arises. This starts to stride from my original question. But I do a so called "unity build" in C which is having only one translation unit and including all the *.cpp files, and not the traditional way of doing header/source files which most likely confuses vs code.

Comment: @Hampus If you open the Problems tab and select an error from there, you don't get the inline message. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @wjandrea This is exactly what I'm looking for. Is there any way to navigate the problems tab with keybindings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you select an error from the Problems view, the inline message won't show, as opposed to using **Go to Next Problem** (`editor.action.marker.next`) or something similar.

In the comments you mentioned you want to navigate Problems with keybindings. Firstly to focus it, you can create a keybinding for **View: Focus Problems** (`workbench.action.problems.focus`). Or possibly:

- **Terminal: Focus on Problems View** (`workbench.panel.markers.view.focus`)
- **View: Toggle Problems** (`workbench.actions.view.problems`)

Once it's focused, navigation is straightforward: mainly arrow keys and <kbd>Enter</kbd>

One of the linter providers I have (ShellCheck) includes a link for more info. I can't seem to find a command to access it from Problems, but I can just press <kbd>Menu</kbd> then select the option from the list: **ShellCheck: Show wiki for ...**